# How to add firebase trigger for any document update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

As described in firebase cloud functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) a trigger must always point to a document. But I want to create a trigger when any document is updated. Assume I don't know which document is updated, how I can add a trigger not knowing the document id?

Comment: Do you mean to trigger for *any* document in *any* collection and *any* subcollection of *any* depth?  Or are there some constraints to where exactly the document may live?

Comment: I meant a trigger for any document in a specific collection.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about document id wildcards. Please read the link again for examples.

Comment: I noted that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase cloud functions offers you the `onUpdate()` trigger. Just look at this [post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentBuilder#onUpdate) from the docs.

**EDIT**

This is a code example from the firebase docs. For more information look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = change.after.data();

      // ...or the previous value before this update
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const name = newValue.name;

      // perform desired operations ...
    });index.js
```

Comment: Can you provide example code? because I want to deploy it as a cloud function.